# Saxon-C CentOS8 Compile

Tags: saxon, saxon-c

I am trying to evaluate Saxon-C 1.2.1 HE on CentOS8 and installation seems to have gone ok. Trying out the samples by `cd samples/cppTests && build64-linux.sh` though leads to a myriad of compilation errors to the tune of the following:

**../../Saxon.C.API/SaxonProcessor.h:599:32: error: division ‘sizeof (JNINativeMethod*) / sizeof (JNINativeMethod)’ does not compute the number of array elements [-Werror=sizeof-pointer-div]
     gMethods, sizeof(gMethods) / sizeof(gMethods[0]));**

Before I summarily and trustfully switched off -Werror=sizeof-pointer-div i checked the source code and what's going on there do seem dubious.

```
bool registerCPPFunction(char * libName, JNINativeMethod * gMethods=NULL){
    if(libName != NULL) {
        setConfigurationProperty("extc", libName);

    }

    if(gMethods == NULL && nativeMethodVect.size()==0) {
    return false;
    } else {
        if(gMethods == NULL) {
            //copy vector to gMethods
            gMethods = new JNINativeMethod[nativeMethodVect.size()];
        }
        return registerNativeMethods(sxn_environ->env, "com/saxonica/functions/>
    gMethods, sizeof(gMethods) / sizeof(gMethods[0]));


    }
    return false;
}
```

more specifically `sizeof(gMethods) / sizeof(gMethods[0])` would not seem to calculate anything useful by any margin. The intention was probably rather to output some code that would arrive at the same value as `nativeMethodVect.size()` but seeing this project's source for the very first time i might be mistaking and the division is in fact intentional ?

I am inclined to guess the intention was in fact closer to b than to a in the following example:

```
#include <cstdio>
struct test
{
    int x, y, z;
};
int main()
{
    test *a = new test[32], b[32];
    printf("%d %d\n", sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]), sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

which output 0 32 which is expected as the sizeof(a) gives the size of a pointer not the size of an array's memory region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That bit of code is to support the feature of user defined [extension functions](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation/index.html#!extensibility) in XSLT stylesheets and XQuery queries. If a user is not using these features then they don't need that bit of code. In fact User defined extension functions is only available in Saxon-PE/C and Saxon-EE/C so it should not be in the Saxon-HE/C code base. I have created the following bug issue to investigate the error above and to  https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4477

I would think the workaround would be to either remove the code in question if the extension function feature is not used or remove the compile flag -Werror=sizeof-pointer-div.

The intent was code is as follows:

```
jobject JNICALL cppNativeCall(jstring funcName, jobjectArray arguments, jobjectArray argTypes){
   //native call code here

}

JNINativeMethod cppMethods[] =
{
  {
     fname,
     funcParameters,
     (void *)&cppNativeCall
  }
};

bool nativeFound = processor->registerNativeMethods(env, "NativeCall",
cppMethods, sizeof(cppMethods) / sizeof(cppMethods[0]));
```